# Apple iPad HIG?

Tags: ios, appstore-approval, hig

Is it against Apple Human Interface Guidelines to make an iPad app that does not rotate to different orientations, if it is intended for kiosk mode operation?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [the app store approval process is off topic for Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The HIG never explicitly states that your application must support rotation. For many applications, it doesn't make sense to rotate, and that's allowed.

Comment: Thanks. Waiting obligatory time to accept. ;)